# 22.04.1 Network Unclaimed

Tags: networking

I have an issue with Ubuntu 22.04.1 I can't connect to the internet. I used the command [Sudo lshw -c network] and have the line "Network Unclaimed".

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:d800(size=256) memory:f8fff000-f8ffffff memory:f8ff8000-f8ffbfff memory:f9ee0000-f9efffff


 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:c800(size=256) memory:f9dfc000-f9dfffff
```

Also, some of my devices that use USB port are not working.

Don't know if I done this code right

`$ sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic' is not installed and no information is available Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.`

Please help
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a fresh install or an upgrade from another release? You most likely have 2 different problems here.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: it a upgrade from 20.04 @David

Comment: @chili555 and I added it I hope I done it right. I still learning linux

Comment: You have a fairly common issue. Ubuntu 22.04 uses a very different network configuration method then the default in 20.04 It sometimes does not get carried over to the new method. Use the info in this site to guide you to setting it up. https://itslinuxfoss.com/ubuntu-22-04-network-configuration/

Comment: Look like it working now thank you!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it.

Answer (score 18):

The package that provides network drivers, among many others, is *linux-modules-extra*. For reasons we don’t understand, it didn’t get installed in your update.

The package is here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic

Please download it on some other computer and transfer it with a USB key or similar. Drag and drop it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer. Now, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot. Your network devices should now be working.

**CAUTION**: *Note to searchers*: It is doubtful that your exact kernel version and therefore linux-modules-extra version is still 5.15.0-32-generic as above, Please verify your running kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

If, as an example, you find that your running kernel version is 5.15.0-99-generic, then that is the version of linux-modules-extra that you need; i.e. linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-99-generic.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I had to download the latest version of linux-modules-extra from the jammy-updates kernel version, and that solved the networking problem.

Comment: My Ubuntu was totally crap after the upgrade, nor network, nor desktop. Installing this deb solved everything. Thank you!
I found the deb here:
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.19/

Comment: Thanks man! I got this problem today for no reason at all. Had to install `linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic` since that was the version shown in `uname -r` and after installation and restart it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the package in the link that @chili555 provided, but I got the idea.

So if you're able to connect your laptop to the internet with a wire/cable, the following commnad might do the job for you:

```
sudo apt reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-75-generic
```

I had the same issue and it worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. The output of `uname -a` on my machine is as follows:

```
Linux xxxx-laptop 5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 15:06:04 UTC 20 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```