# Ubuntu doesnt detect wifi or ethernet. *-network UNCLAIMED in Windows / Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, wireless, ethernet

I have a Windows / Ubuntu dual boot. Both have been working fine for months. Initially I had problems with Windows fast boot and wifi not working, but I disabled fast boot and everything has worked well for months. Today I was in Ubuntu, and I had it restart. Upon restarting Ubuntu doesn't seem to have any wifi or ethernet adapters. Windows is still working fine. I have spent the last 3 hours reading forums and the only thing I figured out was to run: `lshw -C network` which produced the attached output.

EDIT: I found this post with a similar problem. [22.04.1 Network Unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed).

it says to download the files and transfer to pc using a usb drive which I have done. the link provided in the post does not have .deb files though only .dsc, .tar.gz and .diff.gz and I cant figure out how to install this on the pc. Please help

[image: lshw -C network output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, verify that the issue in the link you gave is the issue that you indeed have:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
```

Next, verify your running kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

If, as an example, you find that your running kernel version is 5.15.0-99-generic, then that is the version of linux-modules-extra that you need; i.e. linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-99-generic.

Go here and search for the package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-99-generic but, of course, substitute the exact kernel version you found.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/

To find a download link for the .deb, click on the red *amd64*. You may safely select the closest server if several are listed. Complete installation as in the link you gave. Reboot.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much!