# No networking after automatic updates

Tags: networking, 20.04, update-manager, lts

I ran the Software Updater on my server rig, and now the networking doesn't work, even locally. There's no wifi and no ethernet.

I ran this:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

And got this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Is there a way to see what updates I recently installed to see where this might have stemmed from? Or a way to fix this entirely?

EDIT 1: Ran:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
```

And received:

```
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-70-generic' is not installed and no information is available
```

EDIT 2: Ran: `ip a` and received:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Also ran `iwconfig` and received `lo        no wireless extensions.`

EDIT 3: I also did the steps in the following post. It did not work.
[Ubuntu doesnt detect wifi or ethernet. *-network UNCLAIMED in Windows / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464374/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-wifi-or-ethernet-network-unclaimed-in-windows-ubuntu-d/1464387#1464387)

EDIT 4: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` returns `Status: install ok installed`

And `sudo lshw -C network` shows that my network adapters are unclaimed.

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7200000-f727ffff memory:f7280000-f728ffff
```

EDIT 5: Input `sudo modprobe ath9k` and got `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k': Operation not permitted`

Then input `ps aux | grep Network` and got:

```
root         691  0.0  0.1 261848 19152 ?        Ssl  17:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
noah        2116  0.0  0.0   9040   720 pts/0    S+   17:17   0:00 grep --color=auto Network
```

Comment: May we see the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Results are as follows: `dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-70-generic' is not installed and no information is available`   Thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Can you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu and does the wireless work there? Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464374/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-wifi-or-ethernet-network-unclaimed-in-windows-ubuntu-d/1464387#1464387

Comment: @chili555 It does not appear that I can. I also did the steps in that post, which unfortunately do not seem to have worked.

Comment: Did you download and install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-70-generic or some other. The -70 is crucial.

Comment: @chili555 Exact file name I downloaded from Ubuntu is ```linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-70-generic_5.15.0-70.77_amd64.deb```

Comment: After a reboot, what does this report? `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` and this: `lshw -C network`

Comment: @chili555 Sorry for the lapse in contact. Updated the post with my results.

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe ath9k` Is Network Manager running on this server? `ps aux | grep Network`

Comment: @chili555 Refer to EDIT 5

Comment: "ERROR: could not insert 'ath9k': Operation not permitted" Did you try to compile a driver? Please turn off Secure Boot and try again.