# All drivers missing after changing NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, wireless, nvidia

I recently created a dual boot ubuntu/windows on a new laptop.
everything was working well on both side and i decided to try proprietary nvidia drivers instead of the x.org one but after the install and restart, all my drivers on ubuntu side seem to be missing, no wifi adaptor found, same with bluetooth; display don't support dual screen anymore etc.

Checking the WIFI in terminal say UNCLAIMED, trying to apt-get install --reinstall but since not internet it doesnt work.

I also tried to boot again from the flash drive to reinstall but i only have options to erase all and do new installation, not the one where i could keep my installed apps, documents etc.
If i start with the live version from usb drive it works and cant use wifi and everything.

I don't mind reinstall and restart from scratch but it worry me a bit if it happens again, any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464374/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-wifi-or-ethernet-network-unclaimed-in-windows-ubuntu-d/1464387#1464387