# How to restore my keypad, ethernet, Wifi drivers and connection?

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, internet, touchpad

I accidentally removed drivers or did something to my touchpad, wifi, and ethernet connection.

I have dual boot Ubuntu 22LTS with Windows 10. I was installing nvidia 535 drivers using software & updates -> additional drivers and when I restarted laptop screen was blacked out. Searched for solution mentioning secure boot should be disabled which didn't worked and then according to another solution drivers should be properly installed using command line after purging installed nvidia drivers from root shell in recovery option.

I purged nvidia* and when ubuntu finally got booted and screen showed my touchpad, wifi, ethernet were not working and same are missing from settings. I have tried many solutions none worked for me please help.
I am mentioning some information about my current state I got using some commands:

[`sudo lshw -class network`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Zfn.png)

[Screenshot for commands and output for related information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vALsG.png)

EDIT:
result of `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

`dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-76-generic' is not installed and no information is available`

`Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.`

Edit: Read the similar questions:

- [Ubuntu doesnt detect wifi or ethernet. *-network UNCLAIMED in Windows / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464374/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-wifi-or-ethernet-network-unclaimed-in-windows-ubuntu-d)
- [22.04.1 Network Unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed)

and verified running kernel version:
`uname -r`
`5.15.0-76-generic`

then search for them here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/kernel/
but after finding required package and reaching here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-76-generic/download I am unable to download it using any of the given link. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: I am unable to download the packages.

Comment: Can you download the package on some other computer and transfer it on a USB key?

Comment: That's not the problem unable to download via any link please read edited. None of the link is working

Comment: When I click on your link, the top link is *mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu*. When I click on that, the package downloads immediately. What happens when you click on it?

Comment: Typed on ggogle to find package. From the link I was unable to download.