# Ubuntu Desktop No Internet access after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

recently I upgraded ubuntu desktop from 18.04 to 20.04 after upgrade and rebooting internet connection and the Icon on top right corner is lost I try 2 days googling couldn't find any solution.

here is some commands I run to get info/status.
`user:~$ sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` Output

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`user:~$ networkctl` Output

```
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo   loopback n/a         unmanaged

1 links listed.
```

`user:~$ ifconfig` Output

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4047  bytes 302018 (302.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4047  bytes 302018 (302.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`user:~$ ip ad` output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`user:~$ sudo lshw -C network` Output

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d1200000-d1203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1104000-d1104fff memory:d1100000-d1103fff
```

desktop is connect via cable/wifi but none if them working... but internet is working in other machines.
I have no idea what goes wrong.. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed

Comment: thanks @dominz88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed) was helpful. specially the command.

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
```

after running the command the module was missing So after downloading and installing the required module manually the machine got connection of wifi but not cable.

Once the machine got connection I immediately run the upgrade command to upgrade from 20 to 22 and after the upgrade everting start working.