# Network Card "UNCLAIMED", no USB mouse and not able to connect Android phone

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, mouse, ethernet

I have googled and looked on here for answers to this problem and it seems quite common, but so far none of the solutions have worked for me.

This seemed to start after an upgrade and seems from threads to be driver related.  The built-in network card is Realtek and I have tried another 1G card which I bought some time ago, and that too seems to be Realtek.  One comment was that these cards are a common issue.  Maybe.  The first signs were that I was not able to use my USB mouse, nor a spare I have.  Fortunately, I keep my wired mouse of old and that works fine, as does the wired keyboard.  Then I noticed that when I plugged my Android phone in that it was sometimes recognized and others not, but either way I could not view it in the folders.  It just wouldn't open.  Then just before I went away for a month, the network card stopped working.

I did get the network card working after following one of the suggestions, but I don't know which.  I followed a number of links and tried all sorts.  I had enough and shut down, but accidentally rebooted and it worked.  After shutting down again and returning 2 days later, it had stopped working again.

```
$ uname -r
6.2.0-1005-oracle
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet Controller
Product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor
physical ID: pci@0000:07:00:0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap-listnce.

resources: ioport:b000 (size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory: d2100000-d2103fff
```

I tried this, though option 2 is standard. Still does not work. The stage to "Activate" did not work. The cursor would not move to the button. So tried various commands I found instead, but none made a difference. From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed). I then tried [here](https://itslinuxfoss.com/ubuntu-22-04-network-configuration/?utm_content=cmp-true).

`sudo service network-manager restart` failed, said it was not found.

Not tried this as I have no network:

```
sudo apt reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-75-generic
```

Such things are useless if one doesn't have network!

https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-1005-oracle

Tried that, as a mod of a suggestion, but when I select the link the webpage says error as it's not the same as my machine (my laptop I'm using to download the file), which wouldn't be the same.

Comment: Can you reboot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu and does the ethernet work there? If so, do: `sudo apt update` and then: `sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-1005-oracle` Reboot.

Comment: Yes, I can and no it doesn't.  But thanks.

Comment: Is the package actually missing? `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: says not installed and no information is available.  This doesn't sound good.

Comment: Can you download this to a USB key, transfer it and install it? https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-1005-oracle

Comment: I followed the link and looked for the download links.  A little confused but downloaded these two from the page.  archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-oracle/linux-oracle_6.2.0-1010.10.dsc        https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/23.04/ubuntu-updates-main-arm64/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-1005-oracle_6.2.0-1005.5_arm64.deb.html       ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux-oracle/linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-1005-oracle_6.2.0-1005.5_arm64.deb  I've put them on a USB but the USB does not mount on the PC..  Have just rebooted, just in case that triggers it.  But still doesn't work.  I can't mount the USB.

Comment: You want the deb file. Drag and drop it to the desktop. `sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/linux*.deb` How is the USB formatted? FAT32 is preferred.

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  Busy with school and stuff.  Yes it is.  The USB capabilities have also been lost.  I think it's all in the same package from other blogs I've read.

Comment: @chili555  Having no joy with this.  It's on the desktop, run the command and it just says failed.  With a pc repair co and they get the same.  Please any advice.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ls -al ~/Desktop | grep deb` and also: `sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/linux*.deb` "Failed" doesn't give us much to go on to help you.

Comment: @chili555 I agree, but that's all I had.  I've sent your cmds to the shop and asked them to run them and to feed back directly, rather than me play piggy in the middle.