# No Internet connection after updating to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, 22.04, ethernet

I just updated my Ubuntu to 22.04.3 LTS and I have lost my Wifi and Ethernet connection. It was working just before the update and my other devices are connecting to the router just fine, so I don't think the router's the problem.
I did sudo lshw -C network and it looks like the wireless and Ethernet controllers are detected.
I'm no expert, can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: Since I cant connect to the internet, I'll have to try to download the script and bring It in a USB stick tomorrow. Thanks for the advice, I'll tell you once I try!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it!
Following waltinator's advice (thank you so much!), I entered this question: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)
While I tried several of the methods listed there, what eventually worked was using `lshw -C network`. This showed that, while my computer detected the ethernet and wireless hardware, these were "unclaimed", which apparently meant that I did not have the right drivers installed.
Next I found [22.04.1 Network Unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed). Here, the answer provided by chili555 proved to be useful. I checked my kernel using `uname -r` and entered this page: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/allpackages. Here, I looked for the package linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic (this will vary depending on your kernel), and downloaded it and the packages on which it depends (linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic and wireless-regdb, in my case). I put them in a USB stick, plugged it in my Ubuntu machine and installed all three .deb files using `sudo dpkg -i`. After restarting my PC, the internet was working once again!