# [Kernel version 5.17.0-1035-oem]; 22.04.3 LTS Network unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed version 22.04.3 and I am not being able to connect to WIFI.

I saw this posts:

- [22.04.1 Network Unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed)
- [No Internet connection after updating to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493598/no-internet-connection-after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04-3-lts)

But when I search for my Kernel version:

```
$ uname -mrs 
Linux 5.17.0-1035-oem
```

The problem is that I cant find `linux-modules-extra-5.17.0-1035-oem`. So Im not sure which package I need to use.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)