# Wifi connectivity broken by update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

A recent update seems to have caused problems with my machine's wifi card.  I have it running on a wired connection at the moment.  Prior to the update, I believe Settings->Network had a WiFi section.  Now it does not.  Per [22.04.1 Network Unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed) I have installed `linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic`.  Along the way I installed `linux-headers-generic` and `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (though that one may have been to fix Nvidia -- it's been an eventful update).  I have also poked around in grub and clicked on "enable networking".

At this point I'm turned around, and if a kindly expert was willing to help me figure out the problem I'd be most grateful.

Some system info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxxxx 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Below we can see that the WiFi card is present.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: b4:2e:99:35:2d:26
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=6.2.0-39-generic duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.86.125 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:fdb00000-fdb1ffff ioport:1000(size=32) memory:fdb20000-fdb23fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:66 memory:fd400000-fd407fff memory:fd200000-fd3fffff
```

What additional information would be helpful?

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot.

Comment: Thank you.  That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by chili555 solved my issue.

`sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source` and reboot