# Unclaimed network, missing linux-modules-extra

Tags: drivers, usb

After installing new Nvidia drivers and rebooting, I noticed that my machine no longer has internet connectivity. `sudo lshw -c network` yields `network UNCLAIMED`. Following the suggestion in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed), I used `$ sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` to verify that linux-modules-extra is not installed, and attempted to manually download, move it to my machine via USB stick and install. However, that failed, because attempting to open the USB stick, yields "unknown filesystem type 'exfat'". I assume this is also because linux-modules-extra is no longer installed on my machine.

I am looking for suggestions on how I could recover from this. Unfortunately my machine does not have a disk drive, so the only way to transfer files there would be via network or USB, neither of which are working.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and kernel 6.2.0-39-generic.

Comment: I suggest that you try formatting the USB as ext4 and try again. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you @chili555, this worked. For people who are as ignorant about these things as I: After reformatting my USB stick to ext4, I was unable to add files to it from my MacBook, so I used a Raspberry Pi to load the required files onto the USB stick (but maybe there is some 3rd party software that can do that from Mac or Windows).

Comment: Still surprised that a Nvidia driver update seems to have caused this issue, and wondering what can be done to mitigate such risks.

Comment: I have no method to prevent a recurrence. However, in the several similar cases I've seen, I've heard of no repeats.