Missing ethernet internet in newly upgraded Ubuntu 20.04
I was updating my system from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and the update was successful but wifi bluetooth ethernet speaker and microphone is not working. '''sudo lshw -C net''' shows that both wifi and ethernet network is UNCLAIMED.
My understanding is that the drivers are not present. I have a single os system and not a dual boot.
How should I resolve this? I am a complete beginner.

Hello there. Before posting, please be sure that your question has not been asked before. It seems there is already a duplicate and the good news is, it is solved here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437477/22-04-1-network-unclaimed ! Good luck. Should this not help, feel of course free to ask more specifics.
